# tomar parte de un string Android Studio

Tags: android, regex, split

estoy intentando tomar la parte de unos SMS en una aplicacion de android, la idea es que del sms solo me tome el link, pero el problema es que a veces éste puede contener mas o menos caracteres y estar ubicado en distintas partes del mensaje por lo cual no puedo usar el substring ni indexOf (segun lo que intentè). Lo único que es constante es que empieza en **http:** y termina en **z=16** pero no sè como poner que empiece en http me tome toda la cadena hasta llegar al z=16 incluido. se podrá?

Un ejemplo de mensaje seria algo así

**1ª sms**

ACC alarm!
    lat:-31.424482

```
long:-64.160276

speed:0.04 

T:18/10/31 14:39

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=-31.424482,-64.160276&z=16
```

**2ª sms**

Door alarm!

```
lat:-31.424154

long:-64.162243

speed:0.61 

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q=-31.424154,-64.162243&z=16

T:18/10/31 14:53
```

Mi codigo hasta el momento.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Log.e("PERMISOS","ingresa onCreateView");
 //   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bentrada,container,false);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bentrada, container, false);

    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(INBOX), null, null, null, null);

    String enlace = "";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        while ( cursor.moveToNext() && cantmensaje ==1){//recorro todos los SMS y en caso de encotrar el SMS buscado cambio la variable
            String cuerpo = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("body"));
            String longitud ="";
            String longituds ="";
            String latitud = "";
            String latituds = "";
            char [] caracteres = cuerpo.toCharArray();


       /*    for(int i= cuerpo.indexOf("http:"); i>0; i--){ //empieza el analisis desde la palabra años hacia atras


                if(Character.isDigit(caracteres[i]) &&  Character.toLowerCase(caracteres[i]) != ','){ //Revisando que realmente el caracter seleccionado sea un numero
                    latitud = String.valueOf(String.valueOf(caracteres, i-1, 11).trim()); //toma el numero de la posicion actual y el anterior pero si este es un espacio en blanco lo elimina

                        latituds = latitud.trim();

                }

                if(Character.isDigit(caracteres[i]) ){ //Revisando que realmente el caracter seleccionado sea un numero
                    longitud = String.valueOf(String.valueOf(caracteres, (i+latitud.length()) + 5, 11).trim()); //toma el numero de la posicion actual y el anterior pero si este es un espacio en blanco lo elimina


                        longituds = longitud.replace(",", "").trim();

                        longituds.trim();


                }

            }*/

            Log.e("","Tiene longitud "+longituds);

            Log.e("","Tiene Latitud "+latituds);

                if (latituds != null && longituds != null){
                    final WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.googlemaps_webview);
                    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                    //webView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
                    webView.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q="+latituds+","+longituds+"&z=16");
                    //webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                    //    @Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    //    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/erroryaviene.html");
                    //          } });
                    Log.e("ya viene","http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&q="+latitud+","+longituds+"&z=16");
                    Log.e("ya viene",""+cuerpo);
                    // }
                    Log.e("PERMISOS","ingresa al mapa");
                    // cantmensaje = cantmensaje + 1;
                }

        }
    } else {
        //No hay SMS
        Log.e("PERMISOS","no ingreso a view ");
    }

    return v;

}
```

Comment: La añadí la etiqueta `regex`, porque así algún experto como @Mariano, te podrá ayudar con esto. Aunque me pregunto, si obtienes los mensajes como objetos y si tienen métodos para obtener solamente la URL si el `z=16`  al final...

Comment: Ahi añado el codigo, como lo tengo hasta ahora para que quede mas claro. Yo lo hago con un metodo dentro de un fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java no es mi natural, pero hay dos formas que lo puedes resolver, dependiendo tu entrada de argumento:

1) Si tu texto es multiline, podrías guardarlo como un arreglo donde cada línea es un elemento del mismo y leer la posición [3], suponiendo siempre se encuentre ahí. Si varía de línea tendrías que recorrer el arreglo y verificar la posición que inicie con "http".

2) Si tu texto no es multiline, puedes aplicar esta opción que acabo de hacer: https://repl.it/@ShadowHunter/Tomar-parte-de-un-string-Android-Studio La lógica es que conoces la frase de inicio y fin del substring que quieres buscar, por lo que puedes utilizar la clase indexOf(String s) para obtener tus index bandera entre los cuales está lo que buscar, y pasarlos en la clase Substring(int, int) para delimitar dónde encontrar tu string.

Comment: Muchas gracias genio!! Me faltaria averiguar nomas como filtrar los mensajes SMS por numero de remitente como para disminuir la probabilidad de errores en la app pero èsto fue un paso gigante. De nuevo gracias !!!!